# Integrate service mesh with Istio

Tags: service, mesh, istio

I know envoy is the default service mesh for Istio, we implemented our own service mesh and hope to integrate with Istio. so we can leverage Istio to integrate with a lot of components like eureka, cf, statsd, prometheus

My quesion is where I can find the pilot, mixer,and auth API. if possieble plz tell me briefly how to interact with them in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

All Istio APIs are located in https://github.com/istio/api

Comment: Thank you, and which one is pilot, I can't fiure out, the first thing I need to do is leverage Istio's service discovery ability